# Line not visible on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a line like in the code below, but I get nothing! Have I missed something or what could be wrong? I call this code with `drawObjects(canvas);` between `canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();` and `surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` Help is preciated!

```
    // Method to draw objects
private void drawObjects(Canvas canvas) {

    // Clear screen with black color
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    // Draw line
    if(fingerUp) {
        Log.i("Test", "Draw line now!");
        path.moveTo(xStart, yStart);
        path.lineTo(xEnd, yEnd);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    // Call method draw() in CircleManager to draw all circles in list
    circleManager.drawCirclesInList(canvas);
}
```

Comment: you are drawing a White line.. is your canvas white too? Are coordinates start and end different? Are they definately within screen bounds?

Comment: If you're drawing a line, why are you using a `Path`?  You haven't closed you path either.

Comment: @Doomsknight `canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);` would suggest not!

Comment: @Simon oh woops sorry. Focused on the line. :p Anyway, although drawing a line using path is overkill, it should work. And closing a path is uncessary unless you wish to join start to end, (which is pointless in this scenario)

Comment: Also try `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);`

Comment: @Doomsknight Maybe it's my habit (to always close a path) but I believe that no path will draw if it hasn't been closed.  Then again, I've never used path to draw a line :)  I will check later.

Comment: I'm using Path because I need to draw lines between several point when moving finger on screen, but I'ts not in the code yet. What is better than canvas.drawRGB(0,0,0) ?

Comment: It worked when I used paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, use the correct paint mode:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

This will put it in the mode to draw lines.

There is also `paint.style.FILL` for filling, and `paint.style.FILL_AND_STROKE`.